# WHERE NOT EXISTS - MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, not-exists

I can't get my NOT EXISTS mysql statement to work and it's driving me mad now:

```
$ancestors = mysql_query('
    SELECT * FROM comments e
        WHERE 
            ancestors = "' . $comment["id"] . '" AND 
            user_id != "' . $user->user_object["id"] . '" AND
                NOT EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT  null 
                        FROM    notifications d
                        WHERE   d.target_id = e.id
                    )
', $database->connection_handle);
```

Any ideas?

ERROR:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /<>/<>/functions.php on line 785
```

Line 785:

```
    while($reply = mysql_fetch_array($ancestors, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

If I do this:

```
$ancestors = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $database->db_prefix . 'comments 
    WHERE    
        ancestors = "' . $comment["id"] . '" AND 
        user_id != "' . $user->user_object["id"] . '"', 
        $database->connection_handle
);
```

It returns my results i expect.

the notifications table does contain an entry

mysql var dump =

```
string(46) "Table 'whatever_co.comments' doesn't exist"
```

//SOLVED:::
' . $database->db_prefix . ' was missing from my table selectors.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: Is null a column name in notifications? If so, you've got problems, because it's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: "Any ideas?" --- yes, there is one: fix it

Comment: @amaidment: no, it is just a value `NULL`. It is common to `SELECT NULL` for queries nested in `(NOT) EXISTS`

Comment: Can you try dumping out the full query before running to make sure the variables contain what you think they do?

Comment: Could you please place `var_dump(mysql_error());` after the `mysql_query` and post its output here?

Comment: Also, why the downvotes? It's a newbish question, but the @op seems to have done his best to provide the error description (FWIW)

Comment: I thnk I found the problem. It's a syntax error. will report back

Comment: I was missing my table prefix: ' . $database->db_prefix . ' from comments and notifications.

The reason for the question was its the first time i have used not exists.. and was assuming that was the part that was incorrect. Thanks for all your time. This causes for celebration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing my table prefix: ' . $database->db_prefix . ' from comments and notifications. The reason for the question was its the first time i have used not exists.. and was assuming that was the part that was incorrect. Thanks for all your time. This causes for celebration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NOT EXISTS` is fine. I think it may be a problem with your select. Do you have a field called "null" in that table? If not that is your problem.

I think you are looking for something along the lines of

```
Select * 
FROM notifications d
WHERE d.target_id = e.id
AND e.id IS NULL
```

Try using something like that.

Comment: "Do you have a field called "null" in that table? If not that is your problem." --- wrong. Not an answer

Comment: Thanks. Actually that's all I was wondering. Is the way I have laid it out correct. Excellent. Glad I got it right.

Comment: @zerkms so you can literally "select null"? I have never seen anyone do this nor have i ever heard of it being done.

Comment: @Tony318: `SELECT NULL` is common for `EXISTS` expression, because it doesn't care of the data. If `SELECT NULL` confuses you - you can use `SELECT 1`

Comment: @Tony318: Yes, you can `SELECT NULL`. Just try it in a database of yours: `SELECT columnA, columnB, NULL AS columnC FROM TableX ;`

Comment: I don't know. I just copied the code from somewhere else, put my stuff in. It didn't work.. So I tried somewhere else to see where I went wrong.. But it didn't seem wrong, after about 2 hours of trying to get the silly thing to work I thought I best atleast check if the statement is correct.

Regardless of null, it still returns same rresults. As long as the statement is correct I can get the rest to work.

Comment: "I don't know. I just copied the code from somewhere else, put my stuff in" --- **THAT'S THE BIGGEST MISTAKE**. Copy-pasting code without understanding how it works and what it does **NEVER** leads to results you expected

Comment: The 2 hours = understanding it.

(1)(I am selecting * comments where ancestors = "id i need" and where it belonds to me.)(2)I am not selecting any rows where the notification table contains the same id.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE EXISTS` and `WHERE NOT EXISTS` don't look at the contents of the rows being returned by the subquery. They simply check if ANY rows are returned: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

So even though you're selecting a hard-coded null, which would normally "not exist", MySQL isn't looking at that null - it's looking at the row which contains that null, and evaluates it to "hey, that exists".

Comment: Obviously he has syntactic error in the query, not the logical one

Comment: So you're saying. the select statement is correct. Just something else going wrong?